# Convert Windows Machine from GPT to MBR Partitioning Without Data Loss

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

Is it possible to convert a Windows machine **from** GPT partitioning **to** MBR partitioning without erasing the disk or having any data loss?

I realize that the normal thing most people are trying to do is to go from MBR to GPT, but in this specific circumstance I have a need to go the opposite direction. Information on how to do this seems to be scarce, so perhaps it is not possible. But I thought someone here might have the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the disk is empty (does not seem so here), you need to completely back up the disk, convert it back to MBR and partition it as you need, install Windows and restore your data.

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-gpt-disk-into-an-mbr-disk#:~:text=Back%20up%20or%20move%20all,click%20Convert%20to%20MBR%20disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-gpt-disk-into-an-mbr-disk#:%7E:text=Back%20up%20or%20move%20all,click%20Convert%20to%20MBR%20disk).

> You can change a disk from a GPT to an MBR partition style as long as
> the disk is empty and contains no volumes.